# How to recover an Intel RAID 0 on a Rocks cluster distribution

Tags: linux, boot, software-raid, intel, raid0

We had a Rocks 5.5 distribution on our cluster and wanted to upgrade to 6.2. The "/export" partition was mounted on a Intel software RAID 0 array of 2 identical hard drives (HD) (/dev/sdb and /dev/sdc) and the rest of partitions namely, "/", "/var" and "swap" on a separate (boot) HD or "/dev/sda".

First attempts of upgrade failed, because of a warning saying that it had found raid information on the HD and cannot proceed further. I naively solved this issue by executing:

```
dmraid -r -E /dev/sda
```

The error didn't show up again and I was able to perform the upgrade. Using manual partitioning, I formatted the boot HD, and kept the RAID array unformatted and mounted as "/export" again.

After installation completed, boot process failed, saying

```
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sdc!
ERROR: ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sdc
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sdb!
ERROR: ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sdb
/export1: The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 488378000 blocks
The physical size of the device is 244190638 blocks
Either the superblock or partition table is likely to be corrupt!
```

Booting Rocks in the "rescue" mode, we were able to mount the drives again, although it said that the RAID partition was not unmounted cleanly.

The "dmraid" shows the RAID array, although with errors:

```
$ dmraid -r
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sdc!
ERROR: ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sdc
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sdb!
ERROR: ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sdb
/dev/sdc: isw, "isw_eecceiche", GROUP, ok, 1953525166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_eecceiche", GROUP, ok, 1953525166 sectors, data@ 0

$ dmraid -s
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sdc!
ERROR: ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sdc
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sdb!
ERROR: ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sdb
*** Group superset isw_eecceiche
--> Active Subset
name   : isw_eecceiche_Volume0
size   : 3907038720
stride : 256
type   : stripe
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
```

Here it is the "fstab":

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Sep 15 17:35:11 2015
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=90471019-650c-4901-a8f1-e8cce3fbc059 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=5dae925e-6e01-4442-8f5b-07bfbde7ff09 /export                 ext2    defaults        1 2
UUID=18303228-189f-4fa3-9661-71786323d70d /var                    ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=d14c42ec-e41a-4dbd-b6b8-60afb4aa1b14 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0

# The ram-backed filesystem for ganglia RRD graph databases.
tmpfs /var/lib/ganglia/rrds tmpfs size=2045589000,gid=nobody,uid=nobody,defaults 1 0
```

and "blkid":

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="90471019-650c-4901-a8f1-e8cce3fbc059" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="18303228-189f-4fa3-9661-71786323d70d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="d14c42ec-e41a-4dbd-b6b8-60afb4aa1b14" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb: UUID="M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?" TYPE="ddf_raid_member" 
/dev/sdc: UUID="M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?M-^?" TYPE="ddf_raid_member" 
/dev/sde1: LABEL="Expansion Drive" UUID="BC448C59448C1872" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="66F2-41D7" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/mapper/isw_eecceiche_Volume0p1: LABEL="/export1" UUID="5dae925e-6e01-4442-8f5b-07bfbde7ff09" TYPE="ext2"
```

and also "fdisk" output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x44f45cd4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1      111403   894841856   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          111403      119562    65536000   83  Linux
/dev/sda3          119562      121602    16382976   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00045387

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1      243201  1953512001   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
6 heads, 1 sectors/track, 325587528 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 6 * 512 = 3072 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1           22094       22341         743+  cf  Unknown
/dev/sdc2   ?           1           1           0    0  Empty
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdc3       357936035   357936283         743+  cf  Unknown
/dev/sdc4               1           1           0    0  Empty
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_eecceiche_Volume0: 2000.4 GB, 2000403824640 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00045387

                             Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_eecceiche_Volume0p1   *           1      243201  1953512001   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_eecceiche_Volume0p1: 2000.4 GB, 2000396289024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243200 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Alignment offset: 98816 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

We have access to the "/export" partition and its data is still available in "rescue" mode.

I'd be grateful to know if there is a way to rebuild the RAID metadata again w/o formatting or removing/rebuilding the array.

Any kind of help to solve this issue is deeply appreciated.